# Using Crypto++ to generate random hashes with SHA1

Tags: c++, hash, crypto++

I need to generate a random hash using Crypto++, using SHA1.  At the moment I have:

```
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>

...

CryptoPP::SHA1 sha1;
string source = "Hello";  //This will be randomly generated somehow
string hash = "";
StringSource(source, true, new HashFilter(sha1, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(hash))));
```

When I come to compile, I get the following error reported:

```
error: expected type-specifier before 'HashFilter'
error: expected ')' before 'HashFilter'
error: 'StringSource' was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone help me to get this working?  Is there a much simpler way of performing this using this library?  I am new to using Crypto++ so all help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just specify your namespaces correctly and carefully:

```
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/filters.h>
#include <cryptopp/hex.h>

#include <string>

int main()
{
  CryptoPP::SHA1 sha1;
  std::string source = "Hello";  //This will be randomly generated somehow
  std::string hash = "";
  CryptoPP::StringSource(source, true, new CryptoPP::HashFilter(sha1, new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(hash))));
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.  I thought I had tried this previously, but must've missed something!

Comment: THANK YOU! The cryptopp documentation has **no** examples.

Comment: Documentation is not the proper place to look since its an API reference (you are talking about the links at the top of the homepage, right?). Try the [Crypto++ Wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Main_Page). In particular, the [Sample Category](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Category:Sample).