# runtime comparison of boost SHA1 hashing with md5sum/sha1sum

Tags: c++, boost, hash, sha1

I used Boost to compute SHA1 hash, and then compared the rum time with Linux command `md5sum` and `sha1sum`. The file size is 28G. The `md5sum` and `sha1sum` are both version 8.4.

This is how I used Boost to compute SHA1:

```
void Sha1_Key(const std::string& inputfilename_, uint32_t* inputfile_sha1)
{
    std::string sha1_key_string;
    uint32_t local_sha1[5];

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        inputfile_sha1[i] = local_sha1[i] = 0;
    }

    std::ifstream ifs(inputfilename_,std::ios::binary);

    boost::uuids::detail::sha1 sha1;
    std::stringstream sha1_key;
    char buf[128*1024];

    clock_t begin = clock();
    while(ifs.good()) {
      ifs.read(buf,sizeof(buf));
      sha1.process_bytes(buf,ifs.gcount());
    }

    ifs.close();
    sha1.get_digest(local_sha1);
    for(std::size_t i=0; i<sizeof(local_sha1)/sizeof(local_sha1[0]); ++i) {
      sha1_key<<std::hex<<local_sha1[i];
      inputfile_sha1[i] = local_sha1[i];
    }
    sha1_key_string = sha1_key.str();
    clock_t end = clock();
    std::cout << "run time for Boost SHA1: " << double(end - begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " sec"; 
}
```

This is the run time comparison:

- Boost SHA1: 170s
- md5sum: 54.719s
- sha1sum: 81.795s

The complexity of `sha1sum` is higher than `md5sum`, so `sha1sum` takes 50% more time. But the Boost SHA1 method run time is twice compared with the Linux `sha1sum`. Why?

Is there anything I can improve my code? Or any suggestion to other hash method to use?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Overlapping I/O and calculation. It's not very efficient to do it alternating in the same thread.

Comment: @Ext3h This is the function used to calculate SHA1 so it should include all overlapping and overhead. Otherwise I just need to call md5sum in my code.

Comment: Perhaps sha1sum simply contains a better optimized SHA1 implementation than Boost.

Comment: ＋1 for actually getting the `read` loop right, with `gcount` (I think :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boost::uuids::detail::sha1 sha1;
```

See that? **`::detail::`**

That right there tells you you are abusing an undocumented implementation detail, that wasn't intended for your use.

That SHA implementation underpins UUID generation and wasn't designed to be fast for digesting large sequential streams.

That's all.

Use a proper sha1 implementation (libcrypto, cryptoc++ etc)

- [Generate SHA hash in C++ using OpenSSL library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918676/generate-sha-hash-in-c-using-openssl-library)
- [Using Crypto++ to generate random hashes with SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981616/using-crypto-to-generate-random-hashes-with-sha1)

Comment: Your suggestion works. I tried with openssl, and the runtime reduced by 50% compared Linux sha1sum.